# natbib same author same year with a & b references wrong order

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, sorting

I'm working with the `natbib` package and the `aa` bibliography style for the Astronomy & Astrophysics journal. One author wrote two papers in the same year. The problem is with how the references and citations are sorted. schoier 2006b is being displayed as schoier 2006a.

My bibliographic entry:

```
@article{sch2006a,
   author = {{Sch{\"o}ier}, F.~L. and {Olofsson}, H. and {Lundgren}, A.~A.
    },
    title = "{SiO in C-rich circumstellar envelopes of AGB stars: effects of non-LTE chemistry and grain adsorption}",
  journal = {\aap},
 keywords = {stars: AGB and post-AGB, stars: carbon, stars: circumstellar matter, stars: late-type, stars: mass-loss},
     year = 2006,
    month = jul,
   volume = 454,
    pages = {247-255},
      doi = {10.1051/0004-6361:20054795},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2006A%26A...454..247S},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}`

`@ARTICLE{sch2006b,
   author = {{Sch{\"o}ier}, F.~L. and {Fong}, D. and {Olofsson}, H. and {Zhang}, Q. and 
    {Patel}, N.},
    title = "{The Distribution of SiO in the Circumstellar Envelope around IRC +10216}",
  journal = {\apj},
 keywords = {Stars: Circumstellar Matter, Stars: Abundances, Stars: AGB and Post-AGB, Stars: Carbon, Stars: Individual: Alphanumeric: IRC +10216, Stars: Mass Loss},
     year = 2006,
    month = oct,
   volume = 649,
    pages = {965-972},
      doi = {10.1086/506199},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2006ApJ...649..965S},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

My code:

```
\documentclass{aa}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{sch2006a}
....
\citep{sch2006b}

\bibliographystyle{aa} 
\end{document}
```

In the output bibliography, the references a and b are wrongly associated:

```
Schöier, F. L., Fong, D., Olofsson, H., Zhang, Q., & Patel, N. 2006a, ApJ, 649,965
Schöier, F. L., Olofsson, H., & Lundgren, A. A. 2006b, A&A, 454, 247
```

This happens as well in the text.

Comment: The *entry keys* in your database the  (`sch2006a` and `sch2006b`) usually have no bearing on the sorting and ultimately the disambiguation letter added after the year. In this case you get the result because the name list of the `Schöier, F. L., Fong, D.,` sorts before `Schöier, F. L., Olofsson, H.` (F<O). If you wanted a different sort order you would have to tweak stuff manually or tell your style to also take the month into account (`jul`<`oct`)

Comment: Given that you are using a publisher class I would not bother modifying the style: The output is (hopefully) as desired by the publisher (and if not, that would be a bug to report to the maintainer).

Answer (score 2):

The `aa` bibliography style appears to sort entries alphabetically by the surnames of *all* authors, not just by the surname of the first author.

Both entries have the same first author ("Schöier"). However, the entry with key `sch2006b` has "Fong" as the second author. It is therefore correctly sorted before the `sch2006a` entry, whose second author is "Olofsson".

The fact that the key `sch2006a` precedes `sch2006b` alphabetically is of no consequence.